# How get html from remote url?

Tags: php

***Goood day.***

***I have this [link](http://www.russianpost.ru/autotarif/Autotarif.aspx?viewPost=26&countryCode=643&typePost=1&viewPostName=undefined&countryCodeName=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&typePostName=undefined&weight=1100&value1=2650&postOfficeId=123456)***

***If i open link in blowser i see window*** 
[image: test]

***I would like get html element with id TarifValue***

***for this i use code:***

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.russianpost.ru/autotarif/Autotarif.aspx?viewPost=26&countryCode=643&typePost=1&viewPostName=undefined&countryCodeName=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&typePostName=undefined&weight=1100&value1=2650&postOfficeId=123456');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

***but `echo  $output` show next code:***

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="document.myform.submit();">
<form method="post" name="myform" style="visibility:hidden;"><input id="key" name="key" value="497947">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Tell me please how rigth get html when me need ?***

Comment: sorry,  i dont add insert code, see my answer again please after words but `echo $output show next code:`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/. One of the best I found so far.

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.russianpost.ru/autotarif/Autotarif.aspx?viewPost=26&countryCode=643&typePost=1&viewPostName=undefined&countryCodeName=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&typePostName=undefined&weight=1100&value1=2650&postOfficeId=123456");

echo $html->find("#TarifValue", 0).textContent;
```

Comment: an example would also be nice i think.

Comment: sorry, i dont add insert code, see my answer again please after words but echo $output show next code:

Answer (score 0):

The content of that page is being dynamically loaded with a code in a form. Therefore, to get the HTML, you have to submit the form with the proper code.

I ran the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->load("http://www.russianpost.ru/autotarif/Autotarif.aspx?viewPost=26&countryCode=643&typePost=1&viewPostName=undefined&countryCodeName=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&typePostName=undefined&weight=1100&value1=2650&postOfficeId=123456");
echo $this->to_html($dom->saveHTML());
```

The output was:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="document.myform.submit();"><form method="post" name="myform" style="visibility:hidden;">
<input id="key" name="key" value="675356"><input type="submit">
</form></body>
</html>
```

It looks like a security measure with the code being generated each time. In order to get the HTML you want, you could use cURL to pass the form data with the post method. But to do that, you need to send the proper code.

Comment: see link http://www.russianpost.ru/autotarif/Autotarif.aspx?viewPost=26&countryCode=643&typePost=1&viewPostName=undefined&countryCodeName=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&typePostName=undefined&weight=1100&value1=2650&postOfficeId=123456 please

Comment: sorry, i dont add insert code, see my answer again please after words `but echo $output show next code`:

Comment: Like, I said in my updated answer. You have to pass the form data to get the HTML, but I don't now how you can submit the proper code.